# Remove Embedded Date Spans in R

Tags: r, date

I have looked elsewhere to address this solution, so apologies if I have missed a previous answer that I did not find in my search.

I have some data (80,000+ records) with various time spans per ID. Some of the time spans may fully fall within the range of a previous time span (embedded) and can be removed.
The goal is to mimic SAS code that loops through based on ID and compares the dates on that current line to the previous, if it's embedded it drops it, and starts the whole process over.

In short, if it's the same ID as the previous line(s) and the DateFrom the same or later than a Previous DateFrom and DateTo is earlier or the same as a PreviousDateTo then it would be removed. This would need to continue until all embedded time spans are removed. Leaving only those spans that don't fall in the range of others. I have tried a couple of iterations of loops and some tidy approaches using cumsum and cummax but have been unsuccessful in capturing all the elements needed to complete the process in one run.

**Embedded Span Example**:

| ID | DateFrom | DateTo | Embedded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01A | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 01A | 1/9/2020 | 1/16/2020 |  |
| 01A | 1/17/2020 | 1/20/2020 |  |
| 02B | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 02B | 1/6/2020 | 1/8/2020 | x |
| 02B | 1/9/2020 | 1/12/2020 |  |
| 03C | 1/8/2020 | 1/31/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/3/2020 | 1/5/2020 | x |
| 04D | 1/5/2020 | 1/8/2020 | x |
| 04D | 1/8/2020 | 1/15/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/13/2020 | 1/14/2020 | x |
| 04D | 1/16/2020 | 1/22/2020 |  |

**Embedded Spans Removed**:

| ID | DateFrom | DateTo | Embedded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01A | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 01A | 1/9/2020 | 1/16/2020 |  |
| 01A | 1/17/2020 | 1/20/2020 |  |
| 02B | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 02B | 1/9/2020 | 1/12/2020 |  |
| 03C | 1/8/2020 | 1/31/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/1/2020 | 1/8/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/8/2020 | 1/15/2020 |  |
| 04D | 1/16/2020 | 1/22/2020 |  |

Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
my_fun <- function(x){
  y <- x %>% filter(!replace(ID==lag(ID) & 
                               DateFrom>=lag(DateFrom) & 
                               DateTo<=lag(DateTo),1,F))
  if(nrow(y)==nrow(x)){return(y)}
  my_fun(y)
}

my_fun(df)
```

Comment: This seems to address what I need!